# Python / Jython no module named <module name>

Tags: python, module, directory, jython

I'm getting a `ImportError: No module named msgrid` error. I've read through many stack overflow responses and im not sure whats wrong with the code.

In fact, it works on about 50% of the computers it's run on.

The directory looks like:

```
scripts # directory
| file exporter.py
| __init__.py

    msgrid # sub directory
    |
    | __init__.py 
    | ms2tvgrid.py
```

the import looks like:

```
import os
import sys

from msgrid.ms2tvgrid import <function name>, <function name2>
```

the sys path looks like:

```
'C:\\Users\\<name>\\Application Data\\<application name>\\scripts'
```

edit: for what its worth this is running as a jython script inside another java application. I dont think that should have an effect on the outcome, but maybe im wrong.

edit 2: Adding the msgrid directory to sys path and\or python path didn't work either.

Comment: Please copy and paste the exception instead of just describing it.

Comment: @abarnert the console output is `ImportError: No module named msgrid` and it points to the `from msgrid.ms2tvgrid import <function name>, <function name2> ` line in the script.

Comment: Is that the value of `sys.path` in the context of the **failure scenario**?  Is that the value immediately before the failed attempt to import?

Comment: @DavidCharles that is the sys path from printing directly after the `import sys` line

Comment: The value of `sys.path` could be different in the failure scenario and the cause of the problem.